# cannot figure this out: Key error in DictReader CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am learning python 3 and have no idea what I am doing wrong, all the research I have done shows me it is correct. Yet, I get a key error

```
import csv

with open("csvtest.csv", encoding='utf-8') as software:
    reader = csv.DictReader(software)
    for riga in reader:
        print(riga['ver'])
```

Here is the csv (just random data):

```
name, ver, status, users
archie,26, production,325
```

This is the error I get:

`KeyError: 'ver'`

Comment: The column names have a leading space. Try `print(riga[' ver'])`

Comment: Yep that was it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I was looking at the code, but it was the CSV file with the error. Thank you Mike67 for also confirming it!

Lesson learned, do not put spaces after the comma in the CSV file OR add the space in the Key

```
wrong CSV:   name, ver, status, users
correct CSV: name,ver,status,users

wrong key: print(riga['ver']) ## --with spaces in CSV
right key: print(riga[' ver']) ## --with spaces in CSV (name, ver, status, users)
right key: print(riga['ver']) ## --without spaces in CSV (name,ver,status,users)
```

**Spacing** must **match** in both CSV and the KEY.